# Perl multiline replace at multiple places in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file `temp.txt` with the following contents:

```
CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNCA
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 MANAGED BY DATABASE
 USING
(
 FILE 'TSASNCA' 482M
)
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;

CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNUOW
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 MANAGED BY DATABASE
 USING
(
 FILE 'TSASNUOW' 10M
)
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;
```

In the above file I would like to replace the two or n occurrences of text starting from "MANAGED BY DATABASE" and ending with ")" with `MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE`.

I tried the following and it seems to be greedy and matching everything from the first occurrence of `MANAGED BY DATABASE` to the last occurrence of `)`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/MANAGED BY DATABASE.*\)/MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE/sg' temp.txt
CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNCA
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;
```

Not exactly what I wanted. Then I tried to eliminate the greediness and still no luck:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/MANAGED BY DATABASE.*\)+?/MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE/sg' temp.txt
CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNCA
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;
```

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, try `perl -00` to slurp in paragraph mode instead of `perl -0777`.

Comment: Also, you should use non-greedy asterisk: `DATABASE.*?\)`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot exactly what I wanted. I just started messing around with perl recently. I just ran my command using your suggestion and it worked like a charm.         perl -00 -pe 's/MANAGED BY DATABASE.*\)+?/MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE/sg' temp.txt
CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNCA
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;

CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNUOW
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;

Comment: @texasbruce thank you for the value adding answer to my question. I am on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well your question, but you can use this regex:

```
\*\*.*?\*\*       with S flag (single line)
                  or
(?s)\*\*.*?\*\*   with S inline flag
                  or
\*\*[\s\S]*?\*\*  without S flag
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ4eG1/1)**

Your output will be this:

```
CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNCA
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 **MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE**
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;

CREATE  TABLESPACE TSASNUOW
 IN NODEGROUP IBMCATGROUP
 PAGESIZE 8192
 **MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE**
 EXTENTSIZE 8
 BUFFERPOOL DPROPR8KBP;
```

Comment: for answering my question. This is my first time in a long time that I asked a question on this forum and I corrected the messup caused by formatting. FYI... the suggestion provided by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot helped my to accomplish what I need. If there are other solutions I would be more than happy to try them.